# M2: Impossible reindex

Tags: magento2, reindex

Impossible reindex magento 2.1.11

**In terminal I run:**

php bin/magento indexer:reindex

The first 3 indexes reindex in a few seconds. Reindex stops on the 4th index and this is the end. I waited all night and stood still.

Reindex stops at:

**Indexed category / product associations**

- I try  reset all indexex
- also I try fix issue with deadlock:

https://www.tigren.com/fix-deadlock-error-reindexing-magento-2/

any other solution?

@update
I found one solution:

- Reset indexes: `bin/magento indexer:reset`
- Make sure that no database processes regarding indexing is running
- Open your database administration client like PHPMyAdmin
- Run query: `SHOW PROCESSLIST;`
- Run query: `KILL QUERY` xxxxx (where xxxxx is the ID
  of processes you want to kill)
- `bin/magento setup:upgrade Clear cache`
- `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -j 1`
- `bin/magento indexer:reindex`
- Disable maintenance mode `bin/magento maintenance:disable`

But can anyone confirm that I need kill this both process?

https://prnt.sc/nvbr2e

Comment: Have you checked the logs to see if something is going wrong?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no information in the logs that could indicate some error.

Comment: do you see actual indexer php process id running?

Comment: Where can I check it? Can you explain to me more what you mean?

Comment: type this command in `ps aux | grep indexer`

Comment: https://prnt.sc/nvb6vc

Comment: I could not reindex `catalog_category_product` or `catalog_product_category` locally, they just continued to say processing and never finished. Clearing the stuck database processes did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

change magento to `developer` mode

make sure your debug/developer logs enabled. also check php error logs.

you have to check your database for errors:

```
mysqlcheck MAGENTO_DB --silent
```

then open second ssh session and read your magento logs:

```
tail -f var/log/system.log & tail -f var/log/exception.log
```

open third ssh session and read your strace file:

```
tail -f indexer_strace
```

start your indexer with `strace`, either as root or magento files user:

```
strace -s 99999 bin/magento indexer:reindex 1>indexer_strace 2>&1
```

this will be a little start to your debug.

Comment: MagenX, before this, can you please check my topic update?

Comment: the steps you listed is to hide or jump over the issue you have, it will not fix it.